# Trying to install express getting - ERR! code ENOENT

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Can someone help me troubleshoot this please. Or understand what is going on here.

Learning to use node.js and following a course. However, when trying to install express getting this error, which I understand that for some reason it cant locate a file however, which file is in question:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/ac/.npm/_cacache/tmp/08121495
npm ERR! dest /Users/ac/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/f4/7d/62d2a7a5f2c4ffb04f3147496228443c92b3170dee68ec4c60f90bd14281f34b2c12f469acd27e6c3e83e3742a6510a5be0fe852bf17bd86b1ee6e2eafb9
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/ac/.npm/_cacache/tmp/08121495' -> '/Users/ac/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/f4/7d/62d2a7a5f2c4ffb04f3147496228443c92b3170dee68ec4c60f90bd14281f34b2c12f469acd27e6c3e83e3742a6510a5be0fe852bf17bd86b1ee6e2eafb9'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

My steps:

Installed node js > installed npm > checked both v > mkdir myapp > cd myapp > npm init > npm install express.. starts to load and then throws this error.

I tried searching all over the internet and it seems that the issue is common especially with react.

Using Mac OS

Thank you.

---

Tried multiple ways to troubleshoot on other stackoverflow posts.

npm cache clear

unistall and reinstall node.js

---

I think using solved it...

sudo npm install express